# Necessary Condition for uniform convergence of series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I would like to make sure that the follwing is a necessary condition for uniform convergence of series of functions: :Let 
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }f_{n}(x) 
$$
be a series of functions, than a necessary condition for its uniform convergence is that 
$$
\left \{ f_{n}(x) \right \}_{n=1}^{_{n=\infty }}
$$
uniformly converges to zero.

Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$|f_m(x)| =\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k(x) - \sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} f_k(x)\right|\leq \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k(x)\right|+\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} f_k(x)\right|.$$

Suppose the series converges uniformly on $D$.

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $m-1 \geq n \geq N$ then for every $x \in D$

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k(x)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

and

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} f_k(x)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Hence, if $m > N+1$ then for every $x \in D$

$$|f_m(x)| < \epsilon,$$

and $(f_m)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The uniform convegence of 
$$
\sum f_n(x)
$$
is in fact the convergence of the series
$$
\sum f_n
$$
in a the functional space with the norm $\|.\|_\infty$ (called: "of uniform convergence").

So as in every normed space, convergence of the series implies 
$$
\|f_n\|_\infty \to 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

True although it isn't sufficient since with  $\:f_n(x)=n^{-\alpha}\:\mathbb I_{\{\alpha\leqslant1\}}\:$ the series diverges